Fluent-bit parse only first level keys in JSON
Is it possible in Fluent-bit parse JSON message keys but only first level?
For example message:
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "data": {"inner-key1": "foo", "inner-key2": "bar"}}

Need to parse only key1, key2, data. Key "data" value should be as text no matter how deep structure there is.
How to parse only first level JSON keys and keep all its values as plain text?
We afraid of too many fields in Elastic, it can be difficult to navigate among them becasue JSON structure sometimes have too many levels with differents keys.

I think you can use lua script filtering for this
